# Forwarding Meetings to Room Resources from External Sources

Tags: calendar, exchangeonline

Is there a way to allow a Room Resource in Exchange Online to be booked for an external meeting by forwarding the meeting request?

I found an article that suggested setting the DeleteComments property to False for the meeting room account, however the setting is already false in this environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run below command to process meeting requests that originate outside the Exchange organization:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "Meeting Room Name" -ProcessExternalMeetingMessages $true
```

For more details: [-ProcessExternalMeetingMessages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps#:%7E:text=2019%2C%20Exchange%20Online-,%2DProcessExternalMeetingMessages,-The%20ProcessExternalMeetingMessages%20parameter) and [Enabling External Users to Book Exchange Room Calendars](https://practical365.com/enabling-external-users-to-book-exchange-room-calendars/)

Comment: Thanks Joy, is there an easy way to only accept external meetings that have been forwarded by a user from the same tenant?